# $\theta(vt-|\vec r|)(\nabla\cdot \frac{\hat r}{r^2})=4\pi\theta(vt-|\vec r|)\delta^3(\vec r)\overset{?}{=}4\pi\theta (t)\delta^3(\vec r)$

Tags: real-analysis, vector-fields

$$\theta(t)=\begin{cases} 1&, t>0 \\ 0&, t \leq 0 \end{cases}$$

Let $\vec r(x,y,z)$ be a position vector. In a solution to an exercise, the following is stated:
$$\theta(vt-|\vec r|)(\nabla\cdot \frac{\hat r}{r^2})=4\pi\theta(vt-|\vec r|)\delta^3(\vec r)\overset{?}{=}4\pi\theta (t)\delta^3(\vec r)$$
Can somebody explain the equality?

I would like to offer a good idea, why $\theta(vt-|\vec r|)=\theta (t)$, but I have no good idea:

I know that $f(\vec r)\delta^3(\vec r)=f(0)\delta^3(\vec r)$ but $\theta$ depends on $vt-|\vec r|$ not $\vec r$.

PS:
$$\theta(vt-|\vec r|)=\begin{cases}1&, vt-|\vec r|>0 \\ 0&, vt-|\vec r| \leq 0 \end{cases}$$

EDIT: The book is "Introduction to Electrodynamics" (David J. Griffiths
), problem 7.34, Publisher: Pearson

Comment: Apply what you know to $f(r)=\theta(vt-r)$, so that $\delta(r)f(r)=\delta(r)f(0)=\delta(r)\theta(vt)$

Comment: but $r$ is the absolute value of $\vec r$, so why should $\delta(\vec r)f(r)=\delta(\vec r)f(0)$ be possible?

Comment: $\delta^{(3)}(\mathbf{r})=\frac{\delta(r)}{4\pi r^2}$ so that $f(|\mathbf{r}|)\delta^{(3)}(\mathbf{r})=f(r)\frac{\delta(r)}{4\pi r^2}=f(0)\frac{\delta(r)}{4\pi r^2}=f(0)\delta^{(3)}(\mathbf{r})$. Here $f(|\mathbf{r}|)=\theta(vt-|\mathbf{r}|)$ so that $f(r)=\theta(vt-r)$. My $\mathbf{r}$ represents generic co-ordinates and $r$ is the radial spherical co-ordinate